# SQL Server query involving CTEs, CASE, and subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

These are the data sets that I am using:

```
create table test (
masterid int, 
subID varchar(100),
entrydate datetime
)

insert into test
values 
(1,'A','5/1/14'),
(1,'B','4/1/14'),
(1,'C','3/1/14'),
(2,'D','4/1/14'),
(2,'E','6/1/14'),
(2,'F','2/1/14'),
(3,'A','12/1/13'),
(3,'B','1/1/14'),
(3,'E','2/1/14');


Create table test2 (
subID varchar(50),
corptype varchar(50)
)

insert into test2 
values
('A','N'),
('B','N'),
('C','Y'),
('D','Y'),
('E','N'),
('F','N')

    select t1.masterid
           , t1.subID 
           , t2.corptype
           , t1.entrydate
    from   test t1
           join test2 t2 on t1.subID = t2.subID
```

I have to write a query with the following requirements:

1.) For a given masterID, if the corptype of any of the subIDs is 'Y', then select the masterID, subID, corptype, and entrydate.

2.) For a masterID that has no 'Y' for any of the subIDs, I need to select the masterID, subID, corptype, and entrydate having the most recent entrydate.

Please assume that the list of masterIDs is too long to identify all Y's first, then select 'N's that don't have a masterID in the list of Y's.

My attempt:

```
    WITH cte AS
                (
                   SELECT *,
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.masterid ORDER BY t1.entrydate DESC) AS rn
                   FROM test t1
                )

    select CASE (test2.corptype)
    when 'Y'

    THEN

                (select t1.masterid
                        , t1.subID 
                        , t2.corptype
                        , t1.entrydate
                from test t1
                join test2 t2 on t1.subID = t2.subID 
                where t2.corptype = 'Y')

    ELSE            

                (SELECT cc.masterid, cc.subID, t2.corptype, cc.entrydate
                FROM cte cc
                join test2 t2 on cc.subID = t2.subID 
                WHERE rn = 1
                and t2.corptype = 'N'
                --order by cc.entrydate
                )

    END
```

The final output should be:

```
masterid    subID corptype    entrydate
1           C      Y            00:00.0
2           D      Y            00:00.0
3           E      N            00:00.0
```

Comment: Can you add the output that your current query produces?

Comment: is it smallid or subid?

Comment: Why is masterId = 3 get E in output and not C ? Also, what do you want when more than one record in table test2 has a Y inm it for the samre masterID ? DO you want onl;y one row  or all the 'Y'  rows in test2 ?

Comment: @KevinPostlewaite:I'm getting the following errors:

  Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
  The multi-part identifier "test2.corptype" could not be bound.
  Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
  Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: @VJHil: Sorry, my mistake; all smallID's should say "subID;" I made the change from the original tables so they would be easier to understand, but I didn't make all the necessary changes. I'm fixing this in an edit.

Comment: @CharlesBretana: masterID = 3 does not have any C's for smallID type and no Y's for corptype; therefore, I need the most recent subID with corptype N, which would be E.

Comment: @user,  The last record you inserted is for masterId = 3 and small (Sub) id = 'C'

Comment: And what do you mean "... does not have any C's for smallID type  ..."  the C IS the `smallID`, (or 'subId') right ?  You need to redo your question so that it is clear what is what.

Comment: @CharlesBretana : You are correct, sir; my insert is different on what i posted than what I'm working on. I've made the necessary change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is a strange sort of prioritization problem.  It seems strange because the priorities are coming from two tables.  First corptype from `test2` and then `entrydate` from `test`.

You can solve this genre of problems using `row_number()`.  If I'm correct, then this may do what you want:

```
select t.masterId, t.smallId, t.corptype, t.entrydate
from (select t.masterID, t.smallID, t2.corptype, t.entrydate,
             row_number() over (partition by t.masterId
                                order by (case when t2.corptype = 'Y' then 0 else 1 end),
                                         t.entrydate desc
                              ) as seqnum
     from test t join
          test2 t2
          on t.smallid = t2.smallid
    ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, I made a mistake in my insert in the original post; your query returns correctly! Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.MasterId, coalesce(b.subId, c.subId),
   a.entrydate,  
From test a
   Left join test2 b 
      on b.subID = a.subID
         and b.corptype = 'Y'
  join test2 c 
      on c.subID = a.subID
         and a.entryDate =
             (Select Max(entryDate)
              from test 
              where MasterId = a.MasterId)
```